# Delphi10.2 arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe issue + android NDK

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

i have a problem with Delphi10.2 , building android project
error message `[DCC Error] E2597 D:\android-ndk-r15c-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lTMSCPLib`
both the SDK and NDK folders are in the D disk,i have tried to delete and add the SDK and NDK again and i still get the same issue !

this is my delphi library path : `$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\Release;C:\Program Files (x86)\tmssoftware\TMSCrypto RSXE11;C:\Program Files (x86)\tmssoftware\TMSCrypto RSXE11\Android`.

Comment: TMS have excellent support in their forums: https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/forum. Have you asked there yet?

Comment: i cant submit a question there,i keep getting please try again later, maybe they are having a technical issue @DaveNottage

Comment: @Venom, can you look in the Messages window on the Build tab and copy the entirety of the dccaarm command line and enter that in your post. The issue is a complaint about your command line, most likely that a specified library is not available on the specified library paths, but having the details will be of benefit. Chances are the location of libTMSCPLib.a is not on the path. Maybe have a search for that also?

Comment: solved, just add the search path in project option @blong

Comment: @Venom Hello, I have this problem, can you explain how fix it?  Tnx